# Get a Map[enum, String] from a Java enum with a String field in Scala (Play Framework)?

Tags: java, scala, enums, playframework, playframework-2.1

I have the following Java enum:

```
public enum CertificateType {

    EMAIL("Email"),

    NATURAL_QUALIFIED("Qualified"),

    PSEUDONYMOUS_QUALIFIED("Qualified");

    public final String NAME;

    private CertificateType( final String name ) {
    this.NAME = name;
    }

}
```

What I would like to do is turn that enum into a Map[enum as String, enum.NAME] to use in a Play Framework `@select` function. By enum as String, I mean "EMAIL", or "NATURAL_QUALIFIED"

For a list of objects, I'd use the `.map` function, like so:

```
Organization.all.map(org => (org.id.toString, org.name))(collection.breakOut)
```

But I don't think I can modify that to work with an enum.

How can I accomplish this?

**EDIT:** The annotations are nothing to do with Scala, but are ORM annotations for Play. The code above is a Java enum. By enum value, I mean each enum, as in EMAIL, NATURAL_QUALIFIED, etc.

An example key=>value pair would be "EMAIL"=>"Email"

**EDIT 2:** I have removed the annotations on the enums for clarity.

Comment: Just to be clear, "enum value" is the annotated `@EnumValue`?

Comment: Also, what is the name of the field in the annotation?  I've assumed `value` for my answer in the meantime.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion, and my subsequent absence. Please see my edit for a clearer explanation of what I'm looking for.

Comment: well that makes it much easier! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CertificateType.values.map(e => (e.name -> e.NAME) ).toMap
```

Comment: I think the following should work: `CertificateType.values.map(e => (e.name, e.NAME))(collections.breakOut)`. I'm sorry for being unclear in the original question.

Comment: No problem, it happens. :)  So what's the `collections.breakOut` for?

Comment: As I understand it, `map(e => (e.name -> e.NAME) )` produces a  `List`, which you then convert to a `Map` with `.toMap`; `(collections.breakOut)`skips the `List` and generates a `Map` straight away. I'm a complete novice at Scala, so this is just something else I learned on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Stripping out the scala part that I'm not familiar with, could you not do something like this?

```
public enum CertificateType {
    EMAIL("Email"),

    NATURAL_QUALIFIED("Qualified"),

    PSEUDONYMOUS_QUALIFIED("Qualified");

    public final String NAME;
    private static Map<CertificateType, String> map = new HashMap<CertificateType, String>();

    private CertificateType( final String name ) {
        this.NAME = name;
        map.put(this, this.NAME);
    }

    public Map<CertificateType, String> getMap()
    {   //Return a copy so that any modifications a 
        //user might make won't propagate back to the stored map
        return new HashMap<CertificateType, String>(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had originally been using a Map in the class, but I wanted to remove it and generate a mapping on the fly using Scala.